# How to get data from database when a new message is there

Tags: django, asynchronous, chat, channel

I would like to create something like cat. A page that displays you all your messages and the ability to go to the inbox of each. Now I confront myself the problem of how to do that when a new message is sent by a user of any Inbox he can display on the first page where you can show all the cat from a user, and this with Django Channels. Does anyone have an idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i would certainly got for channels as it get you the ability to communicate back and forth.
Any other solution is going to involve polling and that will make you sooner or later miserable